# Spacing of cells and columns in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, constraints, gridbaglayout

My problem is that the last 2 columns of my second gridbagconstraints variable are spaced out too much. I have used one gridbagconstraint to manage the first column and the second one deals with the last 3.

Sadly, I cannot provide a screenshot due to being a new user :(

```
  import java.awt.*;

  import javax.swing.*;


   public class Main_Window_Frame extends JFrame{

     //The tabbed pane object is constructed
    JTabbedPane TabGroup = new JTabbedPane();
    //Jpanels to be added to TabGroup
    JPanel panelAddEmployee = new JPanel();//This will create the first tab "Add Employee"
    JPanel panelSearchEmployee = new JPanel();//This will create the second tab "Search for an Employee        
    JPanel panelRemoveEmployee = new JPanel();//This will create the third tab "Remove an Employee"
    JPanel panelListAllEmployees = new JPanel();//This will create the fourth tab "List all Employees"
    JPanel panelSysOptions = new JPanel();//This will create the fifth tab "System options"
    //Construct GridBagConstraints for the objects within panelAddEmployee JPanel
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //Add employee panel Label declarations
    JLabel lblAddEmployee;
    JLabel lblEmpID;
    JLabel lblEmpIDout;
    JLabel lblForename;
    JLabel lblSurname;
    JLabel lblGender;
    JLabel lblDateBirth;
    JLabel lblAddress;
    JLabel lblPhoneNo;
    JLabel lblEmail;
    JLabel lblJobTitle;
    JLabel lblSalary;
    JLabel lblNatNo;
    JLabel lblStartDate;
    //Add employee panel TextField declarations
    JTextField txtForename;
    JTextField txtSurname;
    JTextField txtAddress;
    JTextField txtPhoneNo;
    JTextField txtEmail;
    JTextField txtJobTitle;
    JTextField txtSalary;
    JTextField txtNatNo;
    //Add employee panel RadioButton declarations
    JRadioButton radMale;
    JRadioButton radFemale;
    //Add employee panel ComboBox declarations
    JComboBox cbDob1;
    JComboBox cbDob2;
    JComboBox cbDob3;
    JComboBox cbDateStart1;
    JComboBox cbDateStart2;
    JComboBox cbDateStart3;
    //Add employee panel label array
    JLabel[] addEmployeeLabels = new JLabel[13];
    //Add employee panel textField array
    JTextField[] addEmployeeTextFields = new JTextField[8];

    protected String[] DDBirthDate = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07",
            "08","09","10","11","12",
            "13","14","15","16","17","18","19",
            "20","21","22","23","24","25","26",
            "27","28","29","30","31"};
    protected String[] MMBirthDate = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07",
            "08","09","10","11","12"};
    protected String[] YYYYBirthDate = {"1996","1995","1994","1993","1992",
              "1991","1990","1989","1988","1987",
              "1986","1985","1984","1983","1982",
              "1981","1980 "," 1979 ","1978","1977",
              "1976","1975","1974","1973","1972","1971",
              "1970","1969","1968","1967 ","1966",
              "1965","1964","1963","1962","1961","1960",
              "1959","1958","1957","1956","1955",
              "1954","1953","1952","1951","1950",
              "1949","1948","1947","1946","1945",
              "1944","1943","1942","1941"};
    protected String[] YYYYStartDate = {"2012","2011","2010"};








    public Main_Window_Frame() {

        super("Employee Record System");

        setSize(750,500); //set the size of the form

        //This creates the template for the multiple tabs using JTabbedPane
        getContentPane().add(TabGroup);

        //Add the GridBagLayout manager to the panelAddEmployee JPanel
        panelAddEmployee.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //Add the GridBagLayout manager to the panelAddEmployee JPanel
        panelSearchEmployee.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        generateEmployeeAttributeLabels();
        addEmployeePanelObjects();
        addListAllEmployeesPanelObjects();
        addSystemOptionsPanelObjects();

        //This adds the first, second, third and final tab to the tabbedPanel Object
        TabGroup.addTab("Add Employee", panelAddEmployee);
        TabGroup.addTab("Search for an Employee", panelSearchEmployee);
        TabGroup.addTab("Remove an Employee", panelRemoveEmployee);
        TabGroup.addTab("List all Employees", panelListAllEmployees);
        TabGroup.addTab("System Options", panelSysOptions);

    }


    public void generateEmployeeAttributeLabels(){
        //Labels are assigned to a label array
        addEmployeeLabels[0] = lblAddEmployee = new JLabel(); lblAddEmployee.setText("Add Employee"); //Set the text to "Add Employee"
        addEmployeeLabels[1] = lblEmpID = new JLabel(); lblEmpID.setText("Employee ID:"); 
        addEmployeeLabels[2] = lblForename = new JLabel(); lblForename.setText("Forename:"); 
        addEmployeeLabels[3] = lblSurname = new JLabel(); lblSurname.setText("Surname:");  
        addEmployeeLabels[4] = lblGender = new JLabel(); lblGender.setText("Gender:");   
        addEmployeeLabels[5] = lblDateBirth = new JLabel(); lblDateBirth.setText("Date of Birth:");
        addEmployeeLabels[6] = lblAddress = new JLabel(); lblAddress.setText("Address:"); 
        addEmployeeLabels[7] = lblPhoneNo = new JLabel(); lblPhoneNo.setText("Phone Number:"); 
        addEmployeeLabels[8] = lblEmail = new JLabel(); lblEmail.setText("Email Address:"); 
        addEmployeeLabels[9] = lblJobTitle = new JLabel(); lblJobTitle.setText("Job Title:"); 
        addEmployeeLabels[10] = lblSalary = new JLabel(); lblSalary.setText("Salary:");
        addEmployeeLabels[11] = lblNatNo = new JLabel(); lblNatNo.setText("National Insurance no:");
        addEmployeeLabels[12] = lblStartDate = new JLabel(); lblStartDate.setText("Start Date:");
        //GridBagConstraints for the title label "Add Employee"
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        int j = 0;
        //This for loop adds all of the labels to the add employee panel.
        //More efficient than multiple lines of code for each label.
        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
         //If the element is the "Add Employee" label then we give it the appropriate sizes
            if(i == 0){
                 c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0); //Insets are 0, assigned to upper-most top left
                 c.weightx = 0.5; //horizontal weight is 0.5
                 c.gridx = 0; //Place in column 0
                 c.gridy = 0; //Place in row 0
                 addEmployeeLabels[0].setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,24)); 

                }else{
                    //If the element is the "Start Date" Label then
                    if (i == 12){
                        c.weighty = 1.0; //vertical weight is 0.5
                        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START; //Ensures last label is at the edge of its display area
                        c.gridx = 0;  //Place in column 0     
                        c.gridy = 12; //Place in column 12
                        addEmployeeLabels[12].setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));

                        //For every other label, a default size and relational location is assigned.
                        }else{
                            c.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
                            c.weightx = 0.5;
                            c.gridx = 0; //Place in column 0
                            c.gridy = i; //Place in column i (relational positioning based on element index value)


                            addEmployeeLabels[i].setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
                        }
                }
            //Adds each label in the array to the "panelAddEmployee" Panel
            panelAddEmployee.add(addEmployeeLabels[i], c);
            //Adds each label in the array to the "panelAddEmployee" Panel
            //panelSearchEmployee.add(addEmployeeLabels[i], c);
        }

    }

    public void addEmployeePanelObjects(){

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        //Construct lblEmpIDout label
        lblEmpIDout = new JLabel();
        lblEmpIDout.setText("0");
        //Construct radMale radio button
        radMale = new JRadioButton();
        radMale.setText("Male?");
        //Construct radFemale radio button
        radFemale = new JRadioButton();
        radFemale.setText("Female?");

        cbDob1 = new JComboBox();
        cbDateStart1 = new JComboBox();

           for(int i = 0; i < DDBirthDate.length; i++){

               cbDob1.addItem(DDBirthDate[i]);
               cbDateStart1.addItem(DDBirthDate[i]);
           }

         cbDob2 = new JComboBox();
         cbDateStart2 = new JComboBox();

           for(int i = 0; i < MMBirthDate.length; i++){

               cbDob2.addItem(MMBirthDate[i]);
               cbDateStart2.addItem(MMBirthDate[i]);
           }

         cbDob3 = new JComboBox();
         cbDateStart3 = new JComboBox();

           for(int i = 0; i < YYYYBirthDate.length; i++){

               cbDob3.addItem(YYYYBirthDate[i]);
               cbDateStart3.addItem(YYYYBirthDate[i]);
           }

        //TextFields are assigned to a TextField array
        addEmployeeTextFields[0] =  txtForename = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[1] =  txtSurname = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[2] =  txtAddress = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[3] =  txtPhoneNo = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[4] =  txtEmail = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[5] =  txtJobTitle = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[6] =  txtSalary = new JTextField();
        addEmployeeTextFields[7] =  txtNatNo = new JTextField();



        int j = 0;
        //This for loop adds all of the labels to the add employee panel.
        //More efficient than multiple lines of code for each label.
        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){

           gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
           gbc.gridy = i;
           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.weightx = 1;
           gbc.weighty = 1;

                if (i == 0 || i == 1 ||i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 12 ){

                        if(i==1){
                            panelAddEmployee.add(lblEmpIDout, gbc);
                        }

                        if(i==4){   
                            panelAddEmployee.add(radMale,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 1;
                            panelAddEmployee.add(radFemale,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 0;
                        }

                        if(i==5){
                            panelAddEmployee.add(cbDob1,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 1;
                            panelAddEmployee.add(cbDob2,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 2;
                            panelAddEmployee.add(cbDob3,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 0;
                        }

                        if(i==12){
                            panelAddEmployee.add(cbDateStart1,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 1;
                            panelAddEmployee.add(cbDateStart2,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 2;
                            panelAddEmployee.add(cbDateStart3,gbc);
                            gbc.gridx = 0;
                        }
                        //Do not add a text box to title, ID
                        //gender, date of birth or start date

                    }else{

                            //Adds each textfield in the array to the "panelAddEmployee" Panel
                            panelAddEmployee.add(addEmployeeTextFields[j], gbc);
                            j++;
                    }
                    }
                }



    public void addSearchEmployeePanelObjects(){
    }
    public void addListAllEmployeesPanelObjects(){
    }

    public void addSystemOptionsPanelObjects(){
    }

    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKIS0.png)

Comment: _I'am having problems_ doesn't help us much. Try to describe what you are trying to do, and how that differs from what you get with your current code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change my initial response, it's just I was going to provide a screenshot and realised I can't. My problem is that the last 2 columns of my second gridbagconstraints variable are spaced out too much. I have used one gridbagconstraint to manage the first column and the second one deals with the last 3.

Comment: Have you considered to change the Layout? I personally like the MigLayout. However you should change the way you are filling your String[], I really recommend you doing this iterative, because writing down all numbers from `1996`to `1941` isn't a very good idea. And also I would recommend you to use a DatePicker here, because it has a better usability.

Comment: I have to strictly use for gridLayout for this specific case. Additionally, I have to use a comboBox as I can add more code to that object e.g. The adding of values. I have taken on board what you have said and it would be good to use an incremental while loop for each case e.g. while i > 1946 and increment using i--.